# Viewcontroller does not work the second time it is called

Tags: ios, swift

**Here is my code**

```
    self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(contactNVC, close: true)
```

contactNVC = ContactUsViewController.swift

1. contactNVC is working normally.
2. Go to another viewcontroller
3. Does not work when returning to contactNVC.

**ContactUsViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ContactUsViewController is here")
    }
```

First this "**ContactUsViewController is here**" will be printed.
When I call another `view controller` and come back to this `ContactUsViewController.swift`, this "**ContactUsViewController is here**" doesn't appear.

**SlideMenuController /this is code from github/**
https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

```
self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(contactNVC, close: true)
```

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. What exactly is `self.slideMenuController()`? What navigation do you use? Is it inside a navigation controller or something else? Even some more code would be useful, because here seems to be only the code that works.

Comment: @VladRusu add something else?

Comment: Note that `viewDidLoad()` is called only once, when the view controller is loaded. You might want to check `viewDidAppear()` method. That one should be called every time the view controller is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() method. These methods called every time your view controller is displayed on the screen.
Because viewDidLoad() is usually called once, when the VC is loaded. Sometimes it can be called multiple times. For example, if there is a memory warning sent, your VC will unload the view from memory, and the next time viewDidLoad() will be called again. But it will never be called consecutively. So just use viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() method, it will fire when view controller will be displayed, anyway.